# The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value. Key: bookingID

Tags: aws-api-gateway

When I test my API made using AWS API Gateway I get the following error in Postman:

```
{
    "__type": "com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException",
    "message": "One or more parameter values are not valid. The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value. Key: bookingID"
}
```

The bookingID field is not empty.

I used Postman to test an API.